# Applet doesn't show anything

Tags: java, graphics, applet

For some reason, this code will not render anything. Can someone explain to me why it doesn't do anything?

```
import java.awt.*;   
import java.applet.*; 

public class TEST extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int xSize = 255;
        int ySize = 255;
        byte R, G, B;

        for(int x = 0; x < xSize; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < ySize; y++) {
                R = (byte) (x % y);
                G = (byte) (y % x);
                B = (byte) (y);
                Color pixel = new Color(R, G, B);
                g.setColor(pixel);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make the code easier to read

Comment: It's not that hard to read is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to get the modulus of a number relative to `0` e.g. here

```
R = (byte)(x%y);
```

in the first iteration. You're probably seeing an `ArithmeticException` occur at this point. You could simply start from `1`:

```
red = (byte) (x % (y + 1));
green = (byte) (y % (x + 1));
```

Comment: Ok, it renders something now... but only the left most colum (1 pixel thick).

Comment: Yep, that's because another exception is occurring. Read the exception message which will tell you what the issue is.

Comment: My IDE decides not to output exceptions with applets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it is trying to put R G and B values above 255. 
I just added %255 at the end of each one to fix it.
Thanks for your help guys.